# Make portable these P/Invoke calls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I'm developoing an `AnyCPU` application and I'm doing some calls to `CallNextHookEx` and `SetWindowsHookEx` functions, but the VisualStudio code analysis throws me a ***P/Invoke declarations should be portable*** warning on both function declarations.

I understand the meaning of this warning, but I set all parameters to IntPtr to make it 4 bytes on 32 bit systems and 8 bytes in 64 bit systems and I still getting the same warnings.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function CallNextHookEx(
           ByVal idHook As IntPtr,
           ByVal nCode As Integer,
           ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
           ByVal lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    ) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(
           ByVal idHook As HookType,
           ByVal lpfn As MouseProcDelegate,
           ByVal hInstance As IntPtr,
           ByVal threadId As IntPtr
    ) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <Description("Enum used in 'idHook' parameter of 'SetWindowsHookEx' function")>
    Friend Enum HookType As UInteger

        WH_MOUSE_LL = 14UI

    End Enum

    <Description("Structure used in 'lParam' parameter of 'CallNextHookEx' function")>
    Friend Structure MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

        Friend pt As Point
        Friend mouseData As Integer
        Friend flags As Integer
        Friend time As Integer
        Friend dwExtraInfo As IntPtr

    End Structure

Friend Delegate Function MouseProcDelegate(
        ByVal nCode As IntPtr,
        ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
        ByRef lParam As NativeMethods.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
) As IntPtr
```

> UPDATE:

After reading again the doc of [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I've solved the warning in this function fixing the return datatypes to these:

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(
           ByVal idHook As HookType,
           ByVal lpfn As MouseProcDelegate,
           ByVal hInstance As IntPtr,
           ByVal threadId As UInteger
    ) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Friend Enum HookType As Integer
        WH_MOUSE_LL = 14I
    End Enum
```

But I still stuck with the `CallNextHookEx` function.

Comment: Most of your uses of IntPtr are wrong. Only pointer sized things should be IntPtr. You'll need to go back to the documentation.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks for comment, I've fixed the declarations of one function but I'm unable to fix the other (Please see my update).

Comment: Are you sure that the `pt` in `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` is the correct? I would expect `POINT` instead.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε doing the changes that you suggested I get even more warnings (5)

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå If I change the datatype of the lParam parameter to Point I still getting the same warning

Comment: @ElektroStudios Change the return type from `Integer` to `IntPtr`.

Comment: `, ByRef lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As IntPtr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has no CA errors, and is an amalgam of an MSDN example, *some* PInvoke refs and comments.  I have no need for a mousehook, so it is not tested, the CA errors are just gone:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Friend Shared Function CallNextHookEx(
        idHook As IntPtr,
        nCode As Int32,
        wParam As IntPtr,
        lParam As IntPtr
) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Friend Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(
        idHook As HookType,
        lpfn As MouseProcDelegate,
        hInstance As IntPtr,
        threadId As UInteger
) As IntPtr
End Function

<Description("Enum used in 'idHook' parameter of 'SetWindowsHookEx' function")>
Friend Enum HookType As UInteger

    WH_MOUSE_LL = 14

End Enum

<Flags()>
Public Enum MSLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As Int32
    LLMHF_INJECTED = 1
End Enum

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure POINT
    Public X As Int32
    Public Y As Int32
End Structure

<Description("Structure used in 'lParam' parameter of 'CallNextHookEx' function")>
Friend Structure MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

    Friend pt As POINT
    Friend mouseData As Int32
    Friend flags As MSLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
    Friend time As Int32
    Friend dwExtraInfo As IntPtr

End Structure

Friend Delegate Function MouseProcDelegate(
        ByVal nCode As IntPtr,
        ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
        ByRef lParam As IntPtr
) As Int32
```

Important Notes:

Allegedly, `System.Drawing.Point` and the API POINT are interchangable.  I tend to not like to assume  that to be true just because some-guy-on-the-internet said so.  It does seem to work though.

The 4th/LParam arg is changed in `CallNextHookEx` from `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` to `IntPtr`.  Many of the CA warnings can be opened to see exactly what the problem is.  In this case, the text tells that `LParam` was wrong because that structure would be 28 bytes (if I recall the CA msg) which is far too large to be passed that way.

MSDN does it this way, marshalling the `IntPtr` back to the structure in their example. `CallNextHookEx` is called from the local delegate where the structure is received as an `IntPtr`.  In cases where you are just passing it along, it is already prepared, if you need to use it, marshal it:

```
' marshal lParm (intPtr) to structure):
MyMouseHookStruct = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, 
            MyMouseHookStruct.GetType()), MouseHookStruct)
...

' pass along ready to use lParam:
Return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
```

If you add a wrapper, you should be able to do that part in the `NativeMethods` class rather than the code using it.

Relevant [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319524).  Note that CA objects to the return type used in the MSDN article, `In32` vs `IntPtr`

Comment: Thanks so much, all works perfect, just there is a little error in the code, the lparam shouldn't be byreffered, otherwise it will throw an unhandled exception of writting in protected memory when trying to marshal the lparam to an struct, the rest of the code works perfect!

Comment: I have one problem with the design of my code, I made the NativeMethods class hidden (as indicates MSDN it should not be visible) and I put the Point structure inside NativeMethods class because I don't want that struct to be visible then I can't expose the Windows POINT structure to subscribe to events from other class. It is a very big problem if I use instead the drawing.point class? I just would like to know your oppinion about this, maybe they are different in some way but it seems to work equals

Comment: I've solved the little issue by receiving a NativeMethods.Point then taking x,y points and send a new SystemDrawing.Point(x,y)

Comment: I dont know what you mean by making the class "hidden".  I think it is more important to keep the API calls and all the grody magic numbers and such private and expose them thru wrappers.  As for POINT vs Point, I dont think it is a big deal - they are both just x,y structures, but it is also so very easy to just add POINT to the class.  Converting POINT to Point and other API -> NET transforms is a good task to isolate in the class.

Comment: For 'Hidden' I meant the class visibility (in my case its Protected Class NativeMethods), thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class *NativeMethods*

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Friend NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function CallNextHookEx(
           ByVal idHook As IntPtr,
           ByVal nCode As Integer,
           ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
           ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    ) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Friend Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Friend vkCode As Integer
        Friend scanCode As Integer
        Friend flags As Integer
        Friend time As Integer
        Friend dwExtraInfo As Integer
    End Structure
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full source of the class if someone need it:

Usage Example:

```
dim withevents hook as new mousehook(install:=true)
' then subscribe to the desired events...
hook.uninstall ' calls the finalizer
```

( I needed to delete some useful XML documentation because the character length limit restriction of StackOverflow )

```
' ***********************************************************************
' Author           : Elektro
' Last Modified On : 09-26-2014
' ***********************************************************************

#Region " Instructions "

' Go to page:
' Project > Properties > Debug
'
' Then uncheck the option:
' "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process"

#End Region

#Region " Imports "

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

#End Region

#Region " MouseHook "

''' <summary>
''' A low level mouse hook that processes mouse input events.
''' </summary>
Friend NotInheritable Class MouseHook : Implements IDisposable

#Region " P/Invoke "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Platform Invocation methods (P/Invoke), access unmanaged code.
    ''' This class does not suppress stack walks for unmanaged code permission.
    ''' <see cref="System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute"/>  must not be applied to this class.
    ''' This class is for methods that can be used anywhere because a stack walk will be performed.
    ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182161.aspx
    ''' </summary>
    Protected NotInheritable Class NativeMethods

#Region " Methods "

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Friend Shared Function CallNextHookEx(
               ByVal idHook As IntPtr,
               ByVal nCode As Integer,
               ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
               ByVal lParam As IntPtr
        ) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Friend Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(
               ByVal idHook As HookType,
               ByVal lpfn As LowLevelMouseProcDelegate,
               ByVal hInstance As IntPtr,
               ByVal threadId As UInteger
        ) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Friend Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(
               ByVal idHook As IntPtr
        ) As Boolean
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves the current double-click time for the mouse. 
        ''' A double-click is a series of two clicks of the mouse button, 
        ''' the second occurring within a specified time after the first. 
        ''' The double-click time is the maximum number of milliseconds that may occur 
        ''' between the first and second click of a double-click. 
        ''' The maximum double-click time is 5000 milliseconds.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns>
        ''' The return value specifies the current double-click time, in milliseconds. 
        ''' The maximum return value is 5000 milliseconds.
        ''' </returns>
        <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
        Friend Shared Function GetDoubleClickTime() As Integer
        End Function

#End Region

#Region " Enumerations "

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Indicates a type of Hook procedure to be installed.
        ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        ''' </summary>
        <Description("Enum used in 'idHook' parameter of 'SetWindowsHookEx' function.")>
        Friend Enum HookType As UInteger

            ' **************************************
            ' This enumeration is partially defined.
            ' **************************************

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Installs a hook procedure that monitors low-level mouse input events. 
            ''' For more information, see the LowLevelMouseProc hook procedure.
            ''' </summary>
            WH_MOUSE_LL = 14UI

        End Enum

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The event-injected flags. 
        ''' An application can use the following values to test the flags. 
        ''' Testing LLMHF_INJECTED (bit 0) will tell you whether the event was injected. 
        ''' If it was, then testing LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED (bit 1) will tell you 
        ''' whether or not the event was injected from a process running at lower integrity level.
        ''' </summary>
        <Flags()>
        <Description("Enum used in 'flags' parameter of 'MSLLHOOKSTRUCT' structure.")>
        Public Enum MSLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As Integer

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Test the event-injected (from any process) flag.
            ''' </summary>
            LLMHF_INJECTED = 1

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Test the event-injected (from a process running at lower integrity level) flag.
            ''' </summary>
            LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED = 2

        End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Structures "

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The POINT structure defines the x- and y- coordinates of a point.
        ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        ''' </summary>
        <Description("Structure used in 'pt' parameter of 'MSLLHOOKSTRUCT' structure.")>
        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
        Friend Structure POINT

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The x-coordinate of the point.
            ''' </summary>
            Public X As Integer

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The y-coordinate of the point.
            ''' </summary>
            Public Y As Integer

        End Structure

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Contains information about a low-level mouse input event.
        ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        ''' </summary>
        <Description("Structure used in 'lParam' parameter of 'CallNextHookEx' function.")>
        Friend Structure MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The ptThe x- and y-coordinates of the cursor, in screen coordinates.
            ''' </summary>
            Friend pt As NativeMethods.POINT

            ''' <summary>
            ''' If the message is 'WM_MOUSEWHEEL', the high-order word of this member is the wheel delta. 
            ''' The low-order word is reserved. 
            ''' A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; 
            ''' a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. 
            ''' One wheel click is defined as 'WHEEL_DELTA', which is '120'.
            ''' </summary>
            Friend mouseData As Integer

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The event-injected flag.
            ''' </summary>
            Friend flags As MSLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags

            ''' <summary>
            ''' The time stamp for this message. 
            ''' </summary>
            Friend time As UInteger

            ''' <summary>
            ''' Additional information associated with the message.
            ''' </summary>
            Friend dwExtraInfo As IntPtr

        End Structure

#End Region

#Region " Delegates "

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Delegate LowLevelMouseProc
        ''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns>
        ''' If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
        ''' If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message, 
        ''' it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns; 
        ''' otherwise, other applications that have installed WH_MOUSE_LL hooks will not receive hook notifications 
        ''' and may behave incorrectly as a result.
        ''' If the hook procedure processed the message, 
        ''' it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure. 
        ''' </returns>
        Friend Delegate Function LowLevelMouseProcDelegate(
                ByVal nCode As IntPtr,
                ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
                ByVal lParam As IntPtr
        ) As Integer

#End Region

#Region " Hidden Methods "

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Determines whether the specified System.Object instances are considered equal.
        ''' </summary>
        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
        Public Shadows Sub Equals()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Determines whether the specified System.Object instances are the same instance.
        ''' </summary>
        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
        Private Shadows Sub ReferenceEquals()
        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class

#End Region

#Region " Objects "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handle to the hook procedure.
    ''' </summary>
    Private MouseHook As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The mouse hook delegate.
    ''' </summary>
    Private MouseHookDelegate As NativeMethods.LowLevelMouseProcDelegate

#End Region

#Region " Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' ** ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES **
    ''' Gets or sets a value indicating whether to suppress the last MouseUp event of 
    ''' the specified clicked button when a double-click fires.
    ''' 
    ''' If this value is set to <c>true</c>, the application will send the events in this order for a Double-Click:
    ''' MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseDoubleClick
    ''' 
    ''' If this value is set to <c>false</c>, the application will send the events in this order for a Double-Click:
    ''' MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseDoubleClick
    ''' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value><c>true</c> if MouseUp event is suppressed; otherwise <c>false</c>.</value>
    Friend Property SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick As Boolean = False

#End Region

#Region " Enumerations "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates a Windows Message related to a mouse events.
    ''' For more info see here:
    ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    ''' </summary>
    Private Enum MouseMessages As UInteger

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted to a window when the cursor moves. 
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window that contains the cursor. 
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = &H200UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted when the user presses the left mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a window.
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor.
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted when the user releases the left mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a window. 
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor. 
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted when the user presses the right mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a window. 
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor. 
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = &H204UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted when the user releases the right mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a window. 
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor. 
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_RBUTTONUP = &H205UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted when the user presses the middle mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a window. 
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor. 
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_MBUTTONDOWN = &H207UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Posted when the user releases the middle mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a window. 
        ''' If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor. 
        ''' Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse
        ''' </summary>
        WM_MBUTTONUP = &H208UI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Sent to the active window when the mouse's horizontal scroll wheel is tilted or rotated. 
        ''' The DefWindowProc function propagates the message to the window's parent. 
        ''' There should be no internal forwarding of the message, 
        ''' since DefWindowProc propagates it up the parent chain until it finds a window that processes it.
        ''' </summary>
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20AUI

    End Enum

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the whell direction of the mouse.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Enum WheelDirection As Integer

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The wheel is moved up.
        ''' </summary>
        WheelUp = 1

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The wheel is moved down.
        ''' </summary>
        WheelDown = 2

    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Events "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse moves.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object,
                           ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse left button is pressed.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseLeftDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                               ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse left button is released.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseLeftUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                             ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse left button performs a double-click.
    ''' A double click is considered as: (MouseLeftDown + MouseLeftUp) * 2
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseLeftDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object,
                                      ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse right button is pressed.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseRightDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                                ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse right button is released.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseRightUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                              ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse right button performs a double-click.
    ''' A double click is considered as: (MouseLeftDown + MouseLeftUp) * 2
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseRightDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object,
                                       ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse middle button is pressed.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseMiddleDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                                 ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse middle button is released.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseMiddleUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                               ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse middle button performs a double-click.
    ''' A double click is considered as: (MouseLeftDown + MouseLeftUp) * 2
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseMiddleDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object,
                                        ByVal MouseLocation As Point)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the mouse wheel is moved up or down.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Event MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object,
                            ByVal MouseLocation As Point,
                            ByVal WheelDirection As WheelDirection)

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="MouseHook"/> class from being created.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MouseHook"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Install">
    ''' If set to <c>true</c>, the Hook starts initialized for this <see cref="MouseHook"/> instance.
    ''' </param>
    Friend Sub New(Optional ByVal Install As Boolean = False)

        If Install Then
            Me.Install()
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Installs the Mouse Hook, then start processing messages to fire events.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Sub Install()

        Me.MouseHookDelegate = New NativeMethods.LowLevelMouseProcDelegate(AddressOf LowLevelMouseProc)

        Try
            Me.MouseHook = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(NativeMethods.HookType.WH_MOUSE_LL,
                                                          Me.MouseHookDelegate,
                                                          Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw

        End Try

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Uninstalls the Mouse Hook and free all resources, then stop processing messages to fire events.
    ''' </summary>
    Friend Sub Uninstall()

        Me.Finalize()

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    Private Function LowLevelMouseProc(ByVal nCode As Integer,
                                       ByVal wParam As MouseMessages,
                                       ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

        Static LeftClickTime As Integer = 0I ' Determines a left button double-click.
        Static RightClickTime As Integer = 0I ' Determines a right button double-click.
        Static MiddleClickTime As Integer = 0I ' Determines a middle button double-click.

        If nCode = 0I Then

            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Dim y As Integer = 0

            Dim MouseStruct As NativeMethods.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
            MouseStruct = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, MouseStruct.GetType()), 
                                NativeMethods.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)

            ' Fix X coordinate.
            Select Case MouseStruct.pt.X

                Case Is < 0I
                    x = 0I

                Case Is > SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width
                    x = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width

                Case Else
                    x = MouseStruct.pt.X

            End Select

            ' Fix Y coordinate.
            Select Case MouseStruct.pt.Y

                Case Is > SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
                    y = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height

                Case Is < 0I
                    y = 0I

                Case Else
                    y = MouseStruct.pt.Y

            End Select

            Select Case wParam

                Case MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE
                    RaiseEvent MouseMove(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent MouseLeftDown(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP
                    If LeftClickTime <> 0 Then
                        LeftClickTime = Environment.TickCount() - LeftClickTime
                    End If

                    If (LeftClickTime <> 0) AndAlso (LeftClickTime < NativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
                        LeftClickTime = 0
                        If Not Me.SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick Then
                            RaiseEvent MouseLeftUp(Me, New Point(x, y))
                        End If
                        RaiseEvent MouseLeftDoubleClick(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    Else
                        LeftClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
                        RaiseEvent MouseLeftUp(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    End If

                Case MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent MouseRightDown(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONUP
                    If RightClickTime <> 0 Then
                        RightClickTime = Environment.TickCount() - RightClickTime
                    End If

                    If (RightClickTime <> 0) AndAlso (RightClickTime < NativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
                        RightClickTime = 0
                        If Not Me.SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick Then
                            RaiseEvent MouseRightUp(Me, New Point(x, y))
                        End If
                        RaiseEvent MouseRightDoubleClick(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    Else
                        RightClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
                        RaiseEvent MouseRightUp(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    End If

                Case MouseMessages.WM_MBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent MouseMiddleDown(Me, New Point(x, y))

                Case MouseMessages.WM_MBUTTONUP
                    If MiddleClickTime <> 0 Then
                        MiddleClickTime = Environment.TickCount() - MiddleClickTime
                    End If

                    If (MiddleClickTime <> 0) AndAlso (MiddleClickTime < NativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
                        MiddleClickTime = 0
                        If Not Me.SuppressMouseUpEventWhenDoubleClick Then
                            RaiseEvent MouseMiddleUp(Me, New Point(x, y))
                        End If
                        RaiseEvent MouseMiddleDoubleClick(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    Else
                        MiddleClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
                        RaiseEvent MouseMiddleUp(Me, New Point(x, y))

                    End If

                Case MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                    RaiseEvent MouseWheel(Me, New Point(x, y), If(MouseStruct.mouseData < 0,
                                                                 WheelDirection.WheelDown,
                                                                 WheelDirection.WheelUp))

                Case Else
                    Exit Select ' Do Nothing

            End Select

            Return 0

        ElseIf nCode < 0I Then
            Return NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)

        Else ' nCode > 0
            Return -1I

        End If

    End Function

#End Region

#Region " Hidden Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Serves as a hash function for a particular type.
    ''' </summary>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Shadows Sub GetHashCode()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the System.Type of the current instance.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The exact runtime type of the current instance.</returns>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Shadows Function [GetType]()
        Return Me.GetType
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified System.Object instances are considered equal.
    ''' </summary>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Shadows Sub Equals()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified System.Object instances are the same instance.
    ''' </summary>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private Shadows Sub ReferenceEquals()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a String that represents the current object.
    ''' </summary>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Shadows Sub ToString()
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "IDisposable Support"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Flag to detect redundant calls at <see cref="Dispose"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Releases unmanaged and optionally managed resources.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="disposing">
    ''' <c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; 
    ''' <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.
    ''' </param>
    Protected Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        If Not Me.disposedValue Then

            If disposing Then ' Dispose managed state (managed objects).

            Else ' Free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects).
                NativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(Me.MouseHook)

            End If

        End If

        Me.disposedValue = True

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Allows an object to try to free resources
    ''' and perform other cleanup operations before it is reclaimed by garbage collection.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()

        ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in method: Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Me.Dispose(disposing:=False)
        MyBase.Finalize()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

        ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in method: Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Me.Dispose(disposing:=True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(obj:=Me)

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: See, I would *not* make the API calls `Friend` and allow them to be called from the subscriber (I left them so in the answer because that was how you had them) -- even as an internal class.  Part of the purpose of a NativeMethods class is to isolate all the grody old API stuff in one spot.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26006218/1070452) for instance.  Especailly with `CallNextHookEx` which only should/can be used locally.

Comment: No problem I confess that I didn't performed an analisys code on those p/invokes of the other question, I will put a note about that, thanks